# Reference a cell with input from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets, syntax

The final objective is **to reference the last populated (higher row number) cell from a column** (its value).

I found a function that returns the **row number** of the last populated (higher row number) cell from a column. In the picture, the function returns '8'. If we keep adding numbers to the column, the number will naturally increase.

I tried to use that function so that a cell (A2) always displays the **value** of the last populated cell from a column.

The closest I've come is

> ="F"&A2

but that returns 'F8' (see A4), not the **value** of 'F8'.

Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is:

```
=INDIRECT(A4)
```

or

```
=INDIRECT("F"&A2)
```